# Problem with Saving metadata of audio files with id3tool

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox

I have a music file mp3 for which I tried to change its meta data (album) using id3tool . However when I see in banshee or rhythm box its still showing the old name only (After rescanning library also). Any idea why id3tool is not working ?

Using id3tool I changed the below songs album name to new one.
In id3tool its showing as new one only

Filename: Aarya 2 -_Mr.Perfect ~ TrojaN.mp3
Song Title: Mr.Perfect
Artist:     Baba Sehgal , Rita
Album:      Aarya 2
Note:
Track:      1
Year:
Genre:      Other (0xC)

But in banshee or other players, its saying album name as different (old one) only

Comment: What does it show if you right click on the song in the File Browser and choose Properties. There should be a tab in the properties window that displays metadata -- is it updated there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer, these music players prefer id3v2 to id3v1 tags. id3tool writes only id3v1 tags. So we have to change id3v2 tags using some other tool (id3v2 tool is available). For more info check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3